# I'm running train.py from my E:// drive but it's automatically jumping to models in some other drive

Tags: python, tensorflow

```
(tf_gpu) E:\Desktop\models\research\object_detection\legacy>python train.py --logtostderr --train_dir= object_detection\training\ --pipeline_config_path= object_detection\training\ssd_mobilenet_v1_pets.config
2020-11-18 11:47:45.213969: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:59] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-11-18 11:47:45.218668: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "train.py", line 51, in <module>
    from object_detection.builders import dataset_builder
  File "D:\models\research\object_detection\builders\dataset_builder.py", line 27, in <module>
    from object_detection.data_decoders import tf_example_decoder
  File "D:\models\research\object_detection\data_decoders\tf_example_decoder.py", line 32, in <module>
    slim_example_decoder = tf.contrib.slim.tfexample_decoder
AttributeError: module 'tensorflow' has no attribute 'contrib'
```

I don't know why but I've crossed checked every path.
Any help will be appreciated...

Comment: You likely have `object_detection` installed or in your pythonpath from the other drive somehow. Double-check your virtualenv (or conda env) or try re-creating it.

Comment: I've recreated my conda env but still getting the same issue.

Comment: The error is related to Tensorflow version. `Tf.contrib` is removed in `Tf2.x`. You need to run your code using `Tf v1.15` or convert your code to Tf2.x by using [Migrate to TF2](https://www.tensorflow.org/guide/migrate) guide.